# Why is attr_accessor necessary in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I occasionally see attribute accessors/readers/writers in the code for models. Are these necessary if I want to be able to update attributes from the view / controller code?

I am a beginner so I am really talking about basic applications.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

`attr_accessor` is a core feature of Ruby and is used to generate instance variables with getter and setter methods. Its use is never required in basic Ruby (it's a convenience).

In the case of ActiveRecord models, getters and setters are already generated by ActiveRecord for your data columns. `attr_accessor` is not needed or desirable.

If you have additional instance data you don't need to persist (i.e. it's not a database column), you could then use `attr_accessor` to save yourself a few lines of code.

The similarly-named `attr_accessible` — which is frequently seen in Rails code and confused with `attr_accessor` — is a deprecated method of controlling mass assignment within ActiveRecord models. Rails 4 doesn't support it out of the box; it has been replaced by Strong Parameters, which allows more granular control.

Answer (score 27):

If you declare an `attr_accessor` then you can use it as a `virtual attribute`, which is basically an attribute on the model that isn't persisted to the database.

Example case: you declare `attr_accessor :password` in your `User` model so that you can use it as a field in a new user form. When you receive their password in the corresponding `create` action, you can derive a `hashed_password`, persist it to the database, and discard the given `password` (which is done automatically at the end of the request).

Answer (score 3):

Generally it is a pretty good idea to decorate `attr_accessor` for anything on a model that is not an actual column in the SQL table. Rails 4 or not. This gives you clear understanding of what's in the model and what is persisted.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, i use `attr_accessor` for attributes that is not in model/database, but i think it's not necessary using them.